# Number of partitions of $n$ formed by combinations of $2$ and $4$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, generating-functions, integer-partitions

I'm trying to find the number of partitions of a natural number that are a combination of $2$ and $4$.

For example: $$6 = 2+2+2 = 2+4 
\Rightarrow  p_6 = 2$$

So I start by defining $p_n$ as the coefficient of 
$x^n$ in the product

$(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots)(1+x^4+x^8+\cdots)$
= $\frac{1}{(1-x^2)}$$\frac{1}{(1-x^4)}$

From here it seems to me that the partial fraction expansion of this last product will give something in terms of complex roots when translated to the generating function of the number of partitions.

But I don't know how to go from here on to determine the value of each coefficient.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not divide by 2 and consider the number of partitions using just 1 and 2? Reducing the problem may make it a bit easier to some extent.

Comment: Your product formula looks wrong. Why is $x = x^1$ in the LHS product, and why is $x^6$ in the RHS product? Should the LHS not be strictly even powers, starting at $0$, and the RHS strictly multiples of $4$, starting at $0$?

Comment: I think someone edited wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a simple way to solve it without involving generating functions. You have just to choose the number of $4$s in the partition, and then you can uniquely complete the partition with $2$s. The maximum number of $4$s that can appear in the partition of the (even) positive integer $n$ is $\lfloor \frac{n}{4}\rfloor$.

Hence for every $k=0,\ldots,\lfloor\frac{n}{4}\rfloor$ there is a unique partition involving $k$ $4$s. So 
$$ p_n=\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{4}\right\rfloor+1$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is the generating function approach,

Following JB King's suggestion, divide by two and consider partitions of 1 and 2 in which case the sequence of partitions goes,
$$1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,...$$
The generating function will then be,
$$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+...)=\frac{1}{1-x} \times \frac{1}{1-x^2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{1-x} \times \frac{1}{1-x} \times \frac{1}{1+x}$$
$$=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \times \frac{1}{1+x}$$
Now to apply partial fractions to get,
$$=\frac{1}{4}\times \frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
These are all standard bits which translate directly into a formula for term $n$,
$$T_n=\frac{1}{4}(-1)^n+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}(n+1)$$
Now tidy up to get,
$$T_n=\frac{1}{4}(-1)^n+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{2}(n)$$
You now have to undo the effect of that earlier halving.

Your sequence will be,
$$0,1,0,2,0,2,0,3,0,3,0,4,0,4,0,\dots$$
So you could say,
$$T_n=0,\;when \;n \; is \; odd$$
$$T_n=\frac{1}{4}(-1)^{(\frac{n}{2})}+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{n}{2}\big)\;when\;n\;is\;even$$
which is a reasonably elegant answer.